# REST API request in Angular 8 is showing statusText: "Unknown Error"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application, angular8

I am trying to get some data from the server through REST API service. Inside the service.ts I have below,

```
    getCategories(): Observable<Category> {

// Http Options
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST'
      })
    };
        return this.http.post<Category>(this.apiURL+'api', JSON.stringify({"type":"get_categories"}), httpOptions )
        .pipe(
          retry(0),
          //catchError(this.handleError)
        )
      }
```

Which again shows the error as below,

> Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost/test/api", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost/test/api: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }

I have been referring lots of posts, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error

> ERROR ReferenceError: "httpOptions is not defined"

because you are using the `httpOptions` that defined outside of the scrope of  `getCategories`

You should change your code like this.

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category> {
   const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'
        })
    };

   return this.http.post<Category>(this.apiURL+'api', JSON.stringify({"type":"get_categories"}), httpOptions )
    .pipe(
      retry(0),
      //catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

Comment: This addresses one point. Now this section is ok. But even if follow this or passing the headers directly inside the request I am getting error as `Http failure response`. Please refer the second section in the query.

Comment: It's really hard to tell because I dont know you handle the API side code

Comment: Something is strange. If I pass headers, request itself not reaching the API server. Request method shows as `OPTIONS` instead of `POST` if I pass the header

Comment: Do you run angular and server jn different port ?

Comment: Yes, angular and API (Basically laravel on wamp) running on different port

Comment: That is normal because you are using CORS to request to different port. So the OPTIONS request is going first to make a CORS request

Comment: If that is the case, how was it going as post request before adding the header and received the proper response from the server, except the unknown url error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped upto some extend. +1